# Как посчитать символы в JTextArea? Java

Tags: java, swing, переменные

Есть JTextArea, в котором нужно посчитать символы, и я не могу это реализовать. Сейчас у меня есть более менее рабочий код, но считает он немножко криво.
Код:

```
static int S = jta.getText().length();
static JLabel S2 = new JLabel(" Symbols: " + S + " ");
```

Но, он Enter воспринимает как символ, есть другой способ сделать это?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто, перенос строки в Java записывается как `\n`, просто удалите все `\n`, например при помощи метода `replaceAll(str1, str2)`:

```
static int S = jta.getText().replaceAll("\\n", "").length();
static JLabel S2 = new JLabel(" Symbols: " + S + " ");
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, попробую позже, если всё заработает, то помечу ваш ответ как решение.